# How do you get Gosu - Ruby to save the x and y coordinates of a sprite?

Tags: ruby, coordinates, libgosu

I am making a drag-and-drop game with Gosu - Ruby and need to know how to get the computer to save a sprite's x and y coordinates. This is so that I can check if the user dragged the sprite to the correct spot.

Comment: Okay. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to add the @x and @y coordinates into a Sprite class, and call that sprite from your window class. So it'll look something like this:

```
class Player 
    attr_accessor :x, :y #this will allow you to both read x,y and write to (save) x, y
    def initialize x, y
        @tiles = Image.new(...) #load your images for your sprite
        @x = x
        @y = y
    end
    (...other methodds...)
end
```

then in your GameWindow class's #update, you do whatever to the @x and @y, here:

```
class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
    def initialize
         ....window init code....
        @sprite = Player.new(width/2, height/2)
        ...other vars...
    end

    def update
        #this is where your game physics will go, and where you will store your x and y coords for the sprite 
        @sprite.y+= 1
        @sprite.x+= 1
    end
```

end

Obviously this is an approximation just to give you an idea. Don't copy paste this directly cuz it won't work :P